# Alternatives to commons-net FTPSClient?

Tags: java, ftp, ftps

Do you know any good open source library other than Apache commons-net **FTPSClient** to interact with a FTPS site

Regards,

Comment: What's wrong with Apachek commons FTP client?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[ftp4j](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/) provides FTPS functionality and is, IMHO, easier to work with than the apache commons ftp client. Ftp4j is under active development (not by me).

Answer (score 3):

Take a peek at this [comparison chart](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/ftp/jw-0404-ftptable.html) from JavaWorld. It breaks down all of the types of clients by feature, license, and cost.

As pointed out below, this chart does seem to be somewhat old (from 2003).

Comment: Heh, yeah, I didn't realize how old that was, but FTP hasn't changed that much :) but that's a valid point and I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if they are open source but there is a list of some libraries:

1. Sun, JDK: sun.net.ftp.FtpClient
2. JScape, iNet Factory: com.jscape.inet.ftp.Ftp
3. Enterprise Distributed Technologies, Java FTP Client Library: com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient
4. IBM alphaWorks, FTP Bean Suite: com.ibm.network.ftp.protocol.FTPProtocol
5. SourceForge, JFtp: net.sf.jftp.net.FtpConnection
6. The Jakarta Project, Jakarta Commons/Net: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient
7. JavaShop JNetBeans: jshop.jnet.FTPClient
8. Florent Cueto, JavaFTP API: com.cqs.ftp.FTP
9. Bea Petrovicova, jFTP: cz.dhl.ftp.Ftp
10. The Globus Project, Java CoG Kit: org.globus.io.ftp.FTPClient