# 530 User cannot login with FTPSClient

Tags: java, ssl, ftp

We're attempting to access one of our FTPS servers using the same credentials as we would in our standard FTP client. However, when using the Java class `FTPSClient` we are getting the error message:

> 530 User cannot log in.

And nothing else. So far we have the following code (Simplified for the example):

```
public final class FTPSExample {

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        boolean error = false;
        String server, username, password;
        String protocol = "TLS";    // SSL/TLS
        FTPSClient ftps;


        server = "A_SERVER";
        username = /*server + "|" + */"A_USER";
        password = "A_PASS";

        ftps = new FTPSClient(protocol);
        ftps.setTrustManager(TrustManagerUtils.getAcceptAllTrustManager());

        ftps.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));

        try {
            int reply;

            ftps.connect(server, 21);
            System.out.println("Connected to " + server + ".");

            reply = ftps.getReplyCode();

            if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
                ftps.disconnect();
                System.err.println("FTP server refused connection.");
            } else {
                ftps.sendCommand("HOST", server);

                if (!ftps.login(username, password)) {
                    String[] welcomeMessage = ftps.getReplyStrings();
                    for(String s : welcomeMessage) {
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }
                    ftps.logout();
                    error = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            if (ftps.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    ftps.disconnect();
                }
                catch (IOException f) {
                    // do nothing
                }
            }
            System.err.println("Could not connect to server.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.exit(error ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

The above code gives us the following log messages:

```
220 Microsoft FTP Service
AUTH TLS
234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.
Connected to A_SERVER.
HOST A_SERVER
220 Host accepted.
USER A_USER
331 Password required for A_USER.
PASS A_PASS
530 User cannot log in.
530 User cannot log in.
QUIT
221 Goodbye.
```

Meanwhile if we do the same in an FTP client (E.g. FTP Voyager) we get:

```
STATUS:>    Connecting to "A_SERVER" on port 21.
    220 Microsoft FTP Service
COMMAND:>   AUTH TLS
    234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.
STATUS:>    Negotiating SSL connection with server.
STATUS:>    SSL connection established.  All transactions are now secure.
STATUS:>    Connected.  Logging into the server
COMMAND:>   HOST A_SERVER
    220 Host accepted.
COMMAND:>   USER A_USER
    331 Password required for A_USER.
COMMAND:>   PASS *********************
    230 User logged in.
STATUS:>    Login successful
```

Some of the trouble shooting we've tried:

- Changing the `protocol` from TLS to SSL, both suffer the same problem
- Adding the command `ftps.sendCommand("HOST", server);`. We saw that the FTP client was running this command before logging in, without that line we instead got the error: `530 Valid hostname is expected.`
- Using `FTPClient`, which results in the expected `534 Policy requires SSL.`
- Removing the `ftps.setTrustManager(TrustManagerUtils.getAcceptAllTrustManager());` which results in the same error
- Instead of setting HOST, using the user as: `username = "A_SERVER|A_USER";`. Same error message

The server does come with a certificate, which for debugging purposes we are happy to ignore. This is why we set the `TrustManager` as accepting all. Is there another setting we should be aware of?

We have no proxy set, and we're not getting a helpful error message. Googling for `530 User cannot log in.` does not provide anything useful so far. Does anyone have any suggestions?

### EDIT

I manage to get it working using a different package called [`FTP4J`](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/index.php), however if anyone could shed any light on why the `FTPSClient` isn't working, that would be fantastic. Here's the working code:

```
public final class FTPSExample {

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        boolean error = false;
        String server, username, password;
        FTPClient ftps;

        server = "A_SERVER";
        username = server + "|" + "A_USER";
        password = "A_PASS";

        ftps = new FTPClient();
        ftps.setSecurity(FTPClient.SECURITY_FTPES);
        ftps.addCommunicationListener(new FTPCommunicationListener() {

            @Override
            public void sent(String s) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void received(String s) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        });

        try {

            ftps.connect(server);
            System.out.println("Connected to " + server + ".");

            if (!ftps.isConnected()) {
                ftps.disconnect(false);
                System.err.println("FTP server refused connection.");
            } else {
                //ftps.sendSiteCommand("HOST " + server);

                ftps.login(username, password);

                if (!ftps.isAuthenticated()) {
                    error = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Connected!");
                }
                ftps.logout();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            if (ftps.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    ftps.disconnect(false);
                }
                catch (Exception f) {
                    // do nothing
                }
            }
            System.err.println("Could not connect to server.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.exit(error ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

And the resulting data:

```
220 Microsoft FTP Service
Connected to A_SERVER.
AUTH TLS
234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.
USER A_SERVER|A_USER
331 Password required for A_SERVER|A_USER.
PASS A_PASS
230 User logged in.
```

Comment: If you disable the TLS/SSL requirement on the server, can you login with the `FTPClient`?

Comment: Will give it a go, though not got access at the moment so will take some time

Comment: Huh, I've just tried with a different package than `FTPSClient` and got it working. So using the same settings, [ftp4j](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5146835/833070) works. This is very strange...

Comment: In the below answer, the protection buffer size and channel protection lines are the important thing.  That's most likely your issue.      ftps.execPBSZ(0);// Set protection buffer size
ftps.execPROT("P");// Set data channel protection to private--

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I remember that when I have tried to change my code from FTP to FTPS I had the same error and I have solved it using this code:

```
public void FTPSUploader(String host, String user, String pwd,int numPort) throws Exception {
    FTPSClient ftp = new FTPSClient();
    ftps.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
    int reply;
    ftps.connect(host, numPort);
    reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
    if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
        ftps.disconnect();
        throw new Exception("Exception in connecting to FTPs Server");
    }
    ftps.login(user, pwd);
    ftps.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    ftps.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    ftps.execPBSZ(0);// Set protection buffer size
    ftps.execPROT("P");// Set data channel protection to private--
}
```

Comment: Setting the flags, before login,
`ftps.execPBSZ(0);` and `ftps.execPROT("P");` fixed the issue. Thanks for that.